# Howto parse/extract english language text from an unknown format for indexing in Lucene

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, text, lucene

I'm trying to extract all of the 'English like' words and phrases from an unknown file format to index in Lucene. Its basically full of random characters interspersed with blocks of English words. The goal is to be able to extract a high percentage of the words to pass to Lucene to index them - full accurate parsing or a 100%  readable result is not needed. Will any of the Analysers in Lucene do the job, or are there known techniques for extracting the English-like text from an unknown file.

Comment: _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, **software library**, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow_

Comment: OK, I'll re-phrase it.

Comment: Your issue is the "unknown file format". I guess you could just read the stream and extract all printable characters (32 <= charCode <= 127) and build one large string, and then index that?

Comment: that's working "well enough"